# Asterisk configuration for getting Notify to the BLF

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk

i am trying to configure Asterisk server to get NOTIFICATION for BLF.
I get NOTYFY for the SUBSCRIBE at the time of REGISTER but at the time of Running call for the busy user ,no NOTIFY is sent from the Asterisk server.

The Sip.conf File setting is as below:

```
[1111]
type=friend
username=1111
secret=1111
context=dialplan    
host=dynamic    
canreinvite=no    
disallow=all    
allow=ulaw    
allow=alaw    
transport=udp    
qualify=no    
dtmfmode=inband    
encryption=no    
nat=no    
mailbox=11@voicemail    
subscribecontext=BLF
call-limit=20

[2222]    
type=friend    
username=2222    
secret=2222    
context=dialplan    
host=dynamic    
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
transport=udp
qualify=no
dtmfmode=inband
encryption=no
nat=no
```

and the Extensions.conf file is as below:

```
[BLF]
exten => 1111,hint,SIP/1111
exten => 2222,hint,SIP/2222
exten => 3333,hint,SIP/3333
```

In the Above setting, i need Notification For user 2222 on User 1111.
Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

To subscribe to multiple extensions, one have to concatenate those with "&":

```
exten => 1111,hint,SIP/1111&SIP/2222
```

If you also want to pickup calls, you have to put those extensions in the same pickup group.

You can visit the asterisk commandline interface (CLI)

```
$ asterisk -rvvvv
```

to debug subcriptions

```
*CLI> core show hints
*CLI> sip show subscriptions
*CLI> core show hints
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...i got it working by adding one more parameter under general:limitonpeers=yes in sip.conf file.